# How to prevent TOR Vidalia from changing my IP?

Tags: ip, tor

I want to manually change my visible IP in Vidalia, not automatically every x minutes. How to do that in Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is not possible directly in Vidalia. [Tor](https://torproject.org/) is designed in a way that your public facing IP address will change approximately at every ten minutes. However there are some »hacks« which might work.

Vidalia allows you to choose a »new identity«. When you click on that button you'll probably get a new public facing IP address (exit relay in Tor terms). So you can change the IP address within the ten minute period.

However if you want to keep the IP for a longer amount of time for a specific site (say for stackoverflow.com), you have to fiddle around with the `torrc`. You can insert the following line:

```
TrackHostExits stackoverflow.com
```

Now Tor will try to use the same exit IP address for a 30 minute period. The option `TrackHostExitsExpire` allows you to change the time frame. By default it is set to 1800 (seconds).

Another useful option is `ExitNodes`. When you enter this into the `torrc` together with a fingerprint or name of one single Tor exit, Tor will only use this as exit. So your visible IP address will not change as long as you don't change that value and restart Tor. However you should avoid using only one or few exits because this might degrade your anonymity.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the earlier post tor stops using circuits after ten minutes (see this [faq entry](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) for more information). This is configurable through the **MaxCircuitDirtiness** option in your torrc so if set this to, say, years tor will effectively never cycle your circuits.

Be aware that this can be risky for your anonymity! Tor cycles your circuits periodically for your protection and messing with this can make you stand out from other tor users.

Hope this helps! -Damian